# Calling web method from Jquery-Ajax ..Error:Internal Server Error

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am learning JQuery and today what I am making is a cascading dropdown (Country State and City).

My code so far is as under

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JQuery/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#ddlCountry").change(function() {
                var CountryID = $("#ddlCountry option:selected").val();

                $.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST",
                url: "CascadingDropDown.aspx/GetSelectedStates",
                data: "{countryID:'" + CountryID + "'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {
                    alert(data);

                },
                error: function() { alert(arguments[2]); }
            });

            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <table>
        <tr>
        <td>Country</td>
        <td>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCountry" runat="server"/>
        </td>
        <td>State</td>
        <td>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlState" runat="server"/>
        </td>
        <td>City</td>
        <td>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCity" runat="server"/>
        </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" />

        </td>
        <td>
        <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The web method is as under

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Services;

public partial class CascadingDropDown : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            PopulateCountry();
        }
    }

    private void PopulateCountry()
    {
        DataSource ds = new DataSource();
        ddlCountry.DataSource = ds.GetCountryList();
        ddlCountry.DataValueField = "CountryCode";
        ddlCountry.DataTextField = "CountryName";
        ddlCountry.DataBind();
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public List<State> GetSelectedStates(string countryID)
    {     
        DataSource ds = new DataSource();
        var stateList = ds.GetStateList();

        var result = stateList.Where(i => i.CountryCode == countryID);
        return result.ToList<State>();
    }
}
```

But while I am choosing any country from the country drop down, I am getting **"Internal Server Error".**

Could anyone please help me in point out what mistake I am making and how to overcome this?

Comment: What happens under debugging? It's unlikely to be an AJAX/JSON problem, but probably an issue within your GetStateList() method?

Comment: It is not even reaching to that point... I have added break point into that method

Answer (score 6):

You need the keyword `static` in your signature. In VB.net you would use `shared`.

For example:

C#: `public static string DoSomething()`

VB: `Public Shared Function DoSomething()`

Answer (score 2):

`Internal Server Error` means that there's a bug in you server side code. Just launch the Visual Studio debugger and set a breakpoint in your `GetSelectedStates` method. You should then pinpoint the line that is causing you the trouble!

EDIT:

If you're not reaching the breakpoint in the method then it's probably a problem with the parameters passing to the method. Try adding quotes around `countryID`:

```
data: "{'countryID':'" + CountryID + "'}"
```

EDIT2:

If it still does not fix your problem then the best way to find out what's going on is to use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/).

With its help you can track every request that is qoing to the server and what are the parameters. Also you can drag & drop the particular request to Fiddler's Request Builder and re-execute request simply by clicking one button - very convenient way to test your web methods.

Comment: It is not even reaching to that point... I have added break point into that method

Comment: Edited the answer, check it out! :)

Comment: Is it the fact that I am not using .asmx  and in a simple aspx page I have added a reference as using System.Web.Services;  and decorated the method with [WebMethod] attribute?

Comment: The response text shows as "<title>Unknown web method GetSelectedStates.<br>Parameter name: methodName</title>"

Comment: There should not be a problem to call methods from ajax decorated with [WebMethod] attribute. It's just a matter of constructing correct ajax request.

Answer (score 1):

Try decorating your method with this:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public List<State> GetSelectedStates(string countryID)
{     
    DataSource ds = new DataSource();
    var stateList = ds.GetStateList();

    var result = stateList.Where(i => i.CountryCode == countryID);
    return result.ToList<State>();
}
```

It's from the System.Web.Script.Services namespace

EDIT:

Can you try adjusting your AJAX call:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#ddlCountry").change(function() {
            var CountryID = $("#ddlCountry option:selected").val();

            $.ajax(
        {
            type: "POST",
            url: "CascadingDropDown.aspx/GetSelectedStates",
            data: "{countryID:'" + CountryID + "'}",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);

            },
            error: function() { alert(arguments[2]); }
        });

        });
    });
</script>
```

as in, get rid of the JSON response xpectation, and see if it'll work as text?

Comment: But there happens to be no luck yet with this too!

Comment: is CascadingDropDown.aspx in the same folder as the page you've sampled from above?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you don't want to use a PageMethod? These need to be marked static to work properly.

```
 [WebMethod]
public static List<State> GetSelectedStates(string countryID)
{     
    DataSource ds = new DataSource();
    var stateList = ds.GetStateList();

    var result = stateList.Where(i => i.CountryCode == countryID);
    return result.ToList<State>();
}
```

As far as I know, this is the only way that you can put a WebMethod into an ASPX page, other than using a WebService.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen an answer to this, so I'm going to post mine. You need to set `ArgementName` equal to something. At least that is what solved it for me.

Take a look at my javascript

```
var teamID = 123;
        var playerID = 456;
        var active = true;
        var webMethod = 'Service1.asmx/HelloWorld'
        var parameters = "{'active':'" + active +
                 "','team_id':'" + teamID +
                 "','player_id':'" + playerID + "'}"

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: webMethod,
            data: '{ArgumentName:"'+ parameters +'"}', 
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(msg) {
                document.write('all good' + var_dump(msg));
            },
            error: function(e) {
                document.write('err' + var_dump(e));
            }
        });
        function var_dump(obj) {
            var obj_members = "";
            var sep = "";
            for (var key in obj) {
                obj_members += sep + key + ":" + obj[key];
                sep = ", ";
            }
            return ("[" + obj_members + "]");
        }
```